# Using Visual Objects RDD and ADS 11 on encryption using supplied AX_SetPassword method

Tags: advantage-database-server

This code does not work:

```
METHOD AX_SetPassword( szEncodeKey AS STRING ) AS VOID PASCAL CLASS 
ADSDataServer

    // Set password for record encryption

    DbInfo( DBI_AXS_SET_PASSWORD, String2Psz( szEncodeKey ) )

    RETURN
```

The error message is: `Operation is not supported by the current RDD.`

I am using AXDBFCDX following the procedure described in the ADS help file.

Any clue to make this work?

Comment: I don't know anything about Visual Objects, but according to the help file: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage8.1/mergedProjects/adsvo/adsvo/ax_setpassword.htm You should be calling `AX_SetPassword(...)` directly. What's the purpose of the `DbInf...` line?

Answer (score 2):

This question is answered in [Advantage Forum](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/forum/questions/1619/using-visual-objects-rdd-and-ads-11-on-encryption-using-supplied-ax_setpassword-method)